# Why use obscure nameservers?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-hosting

I have noticed that most nameservers for "The Big Guys" use strange domains.  Why don't they use their primary domain for nameservers like NSX.register.com or NSX.godaddy.com or NSX.dreamhost.com ?

They tend to use something obscure.  Is there some reasoning behind this, or is it just "how it's done"?

Comment: Examples? Google is using Google.com NS, Microsoft is using MSFT.net, Facebook is using Facebook.com, and so on. Twitter's using Dynect.net which is a pretty prominent provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work in the web hosting industry for a smaller host. We all do this for two reason: First (and this is a corporate choice) we(my company) keep our .com for any system that our client may be using like portal. or support. .

I think the biggest reason we do it is for our resellers. They don't like people knowing that they are reselling and want to obscure that fact. So instead of using NS.company.net we have a white label domain registered through our parent company. That way our resellers can point their clients to our DNS servers without any confusion.

That would explain why nearly every other company usually uses NS.company.com as pointed out in the comments above.